# Telerik MVC Grid Hierarchy - No Child Records

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am trying to display hierarchical data in a telerik/kendo grid.  The data comes from a database view (imported as a model) that contains a list of electrical interruptions. The primary key is interruptionID  There is a field in the view called ParentOutage which if populated with the InterruptionID of another interruption will relate the 2 records.  I followed Telerik's example/demo to the letter yet I cannot get the grid to display any child records.  The event that populates the child records never fires. I've tried hard coding the values that are passed to the getChildOutages function to see if there was an issue there but it still never fired. Each row in the grid shows up with the arrow to expand the record but when you expand it just a small blank space appears.  Also only a few records have child records so the arrow shouldn't be appearing beside every record.  I've posted my code below:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    @Code


        Html.Kendo.Grid(Of vw_ElectInterruptions)() _
                                                                                               .Name("gridInterruptions") _
                                           .Columns(Sub(c)
                                                            c.Bound(Function(p) p.InterruptionID).Width(75).Sortable(True).Title("ID")
                                                            c.Bound(Function(p) p.ParentOutage).Width(85).Sortable(True).Title("Parent ID")
                                                            c.Bound(Function(p) p.Description).Width(175).Sortable(True).Title("Description")
                                                            c.Bound(Function(p) p.CircuitOrArea).Width(150).Sortable(True).Title("Area/Circuit")
                                                            c.Bound(Function(p) p.TimeOff).Width(100).Sortable(True).Title("TimeOff").Format("{0:dd-MMM-yy hh:mm}")
                                                            c.Bound(Function(p) p.TimeOn).Width(100).Sortable(True).Title("TimeOn").Format("{0:dd-MMM-yy hh:mm}")

                                                    End Sub) _
                                                    .Events(Function(e) e.DataBound("dataBound")) _
                                                    .ClientDetailTemplateId("template") _
                                                    .AutoBind(True) _
                                                    .Sortable(Sub(d) d.SortMode(GridSortMode.SingleColumn).AllowUnsort(False)) _
                                                    .Filterable() _
                                                        .HtmlAttributes(New With {.Style = "height:500px;"}) _
                                                                                .Pageable(Sub(d) d.PageSizes(True).ButtonCount(5).Refresh(True)) _
                                                                                                        .DataSource(Sub(d)
                                                                                                                            d.Ajax() _
                                                                                                                            .Sort(Sub(sort)
                                                                                                                                          sort.Add("TimeOff").Descending()
                                                                                                                                          sort.Add("InterruptionID").Ascending()
                                                                                                                                  End Sub) _
                                                                                                                            .PageSize(25) _
                                                                                                                            .ServerOperation(False) _
                                                                                                                            .Read(Function(read) read.Action("ElecInterruptionRefreshGrid", "Application")) _
                                                                                                                            .Events(Sub(e)
                                                                                                                                            e.Error("grid_error")
                                                                                                                                    End Sub)
                                                                                                                    End Sub).Render()


    End Code

</div>
```

```js
<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    @Code
        Html.Kendo.Grid(Of vw_ElectInterruptions)() _
                                                                                                      .Name("childInterruptions_#=InterruptionID#") _
                                                  .Columns(Sub(c)
                                                                   c.Bound(Function(p) p.InterruptionID).Width(75).Sortable(True).Title("ID")
                                                                   c.Bound(Function(p) p.Description).Width(175).Sortable(True).Title("Description")
                                                                   c.Bound(Function(p) p.CircuitOrArea).Width(150).Sortable(True).Title("Area/Circuit")
                                                                   c.Bound(Function(p) p.TimeOff).Width(100).Sortable(True).Title("TimeOff").Format("{0:dd-MMM-yy hh:mm}")
                                                                   c.Bound(Function(p) p.TimeOn).Width(100).Sortable(True).Title("TimeOn").Format("{0:dd-MMM-yy hh:mm}")


                                                           End Sub) _
                                                                    .DataSource(Sub(d)
                                                                                        d.Ajax() _
                                                                                        .Read(Function(read) read.Action("GetChildOutages", "Application", New With {.id = "#=InterruptionID#"}))
                                                                                        
                                                                             
                                                                                End Sub).ToClientTemplate()
    End Code
   
</script>

    <script>
        function dataBound() {
            this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
        }
    </script>
```

```
And the controller code:

     Public Function ElecInterruptionRefreshGrid(request As DataSourceRequest) As ActionResult

                Dim model = db.vw_ElectInterruptions.ToList

                Dim jsonResult = Json(model.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
                jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue
                Return jsonResult

        End Function

    Public Function GetChildOutages(id As Integer, request As DataSourceRequest) As ActionResult


                Dim model = db.vw_ElectInterruptions.Where(Function(w) w.ParentOutage = id).ToList

                Dim jsonResult = Json(model.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
                jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue
                Return jsonResult

        End Function
```

Comment: Firstly, I would strongly suggest improving the indentation on this post. Secondly, are you getting any errors in the console window when attempting to expand a row?

Comment: Sorry about the indentation - Visual Studio doesn't seem to be able to properly handle razor code/html and always messes up my indents - i fix them and then they go back to the way they are.  I was able to solve the problem and posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I spent hours on this and then found the answer within minutes after posting this question.  Apparently it didn't like the fact that I put the child grid template inside a @Code ... End Code - block.   I changed the template script to look like this and it started working:

```js
 @(Html.Kendo.Grid(Of vw_ElectInterruptions)() _
                                                                                                      .Name("childInterruptions_#=InterruptionID#") _
                                                  .Columns(Sub(c)
                                                                   c.Bound(Function(p) p.InterruptionID).Width(75).Sortable(True).Title("ID")
                                                                   c.Bound(Function(p) p.Description).Width(175).Sortable(True).Title("Description")
                                                                   c.Bound(Function(p) p.CircuitOrArea).Width(150).Sortable(True).Title("Area/Circuit")
                                                                   c.Bound(Function(p) p.TimeOff).Width(100).Sortable(True).Title("TimeOff").Format("{0:dd-MMM-yy hh:mm}")
                                                                   c.Bound(Function(p) p.TimeOn).Width(100).Sortable(True).Title("TimeOn").Format("{0:dd-MMM-yy hh:mm}")


                                                           End Sub).AutoBind(True) _
                                                                    .DataSource(Sub(d)
                                                                                        d.Ajax() _
                                                                                        .Read(Function(read) read.Action("GetChildOutages", "Application", New With {.id = "#=InterruptionID#"}))
                                                                                        
                                                                             
                                                                                End Sub).ToClientTemplate())
```

Not sure why that would make a difference.